# Will ubuntu media stream like windows?

Tags: multimedia, mediaserver

I have many wireless devices and am in process of building an ubuntu media tower, i am wondering if i can stream from my pc to other devices like windows? Thanks in advance
!

Answer (score 0):

[This forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1837109) from [this google search](http://google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu%20stream%20media%20to%20ipad) says that [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) is good, and you can get it on the [Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xbmc/). It may be able to stream to various devices.

However, I had mixed results with it, so you could try using [Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/), and use the [Spotify for Linux preview](https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/previews/)

You could also use [apache2](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html) to host a web server on your local IP address, and save your mp3/4s in the `/var/www/` folder, as outlined in [this post](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/streaming-mp4s-ipad-ubuntu-41525.html).

Finally, [Air Video Server](http://ubuntuguide.net/stream-videos-to-iphoneipad-with-airvideo-in-ubuntu-11-0410-1010-04) for streaming just to iPad or `rygel`, a program explained [here](http://spacemonkeypdx.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-stream-video-from-ubuntu-to.html), from [this google search](http://google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu+stream+to+android).

It is always prefered that you do some research before asking here, as there is lots out there about this.